# Is this white flaky powder in this tea "vanilla flavor"?

Tags: tea, vanilla

I got some tea from Thailand as a gift, and it has some vanilla flavor to it:

[image]

Obviously, it smells a lot like vanilla. This is how the tea looks like:

[image]

Is the white powdery stuff (looks a bit flaky when it's larger), mostly on the left this "vanilla flavor"? Is this natural vanilla, or synthetic? If it's not the white stuff, what is it?

Comment: It's probably vanellin powder.  (artificial vanilla ...  "vanilla powder" would be off-white)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. This looks like very low quality 'tea', where they put in ground stalks instead of (only) leaves. Given that quality, there could be any other 'ingredients' in it.